# Generate Avro schema from C# record

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, reflection, avro

Is there a possibility to generate an Avro schema out of a C# record. I found the Avro.Reflect namespace, which has an AvroFieldAttribute to (I guess) annotate properties, but I can not figure out how to get the schema out of an annotated object.